# Xapian filtering with whitespace

Tags: c++, xapian

How to filter search result with query with has white space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <xapian.h>
struct document{
    std::string title;
    std::string content;
    std::string url;
};

void indexData(document d) {
    try {
        Xapian::WritableDatabase db("/Users/ramesh/Desktop/xapian", Xapian::DB_CREATE_OR_OPEN);
        Xapian::TermGenerator indexer;
        Xapian::Stem stemmer("english");
        indexer.set_stemmer(stemmer);
        Xapian::Document doc;
        doc.set_data(d.title);
        indexer.set_document(doc);
        indexer.index_text(d.title,1,"title");
        indexer.index_text(d.content,1,"content");
        indexer.index_text(d.url,1,"url");
        doc.add_boolean_term("title"+d.title);
        db.replace_document(d.url,doc);
        db.commit();
    } catch (const Xapian::Error &e) {
        std::cout << e.get_description() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void searchData(std::string query_string){
    try{
        Xapian::Database db("/Users/ramesh/Desktop/xapian");
        Xapian::Enquire enquire(db);
        Xapian::QueryParser qp;
        Xapian::Stem stemmer("english");
        qp.set_default_op(Xapian::Query::OP_FILTER);
        qp.set_stemmer(stemmer);
        qp.add_prefix("","title");
        qp.add_prefix("","content");
        qp.add_boolean_prefix("title","title");
        qp.set_database(db);
        qp.set_stemming_strategy(Xapian::QueryParser::STEM_SOME);
        Xapian::Query query = qp.parse_query(query_string);
        std::cout << "Parsed query is: " << query.get_description() << std::endl;
        enquire.set_query(query);
        Xapian::MSet matches = enquire.get_mset(0, 10);
        std::cout << matches.get_matches_estimated() << " results found.\n";
        std::cout << "Matches 1-" << matches.size() << ":\n" << std::endl;
        for (Xapian::MSetIterator i = matches.begin(); i != matches.end(); ++i) {
            std::cout << i.get_rank() + 1 << ": " << i.get_weight() << " docid=" << *i
                 << " [" << i.get_document().get_data() << "]\n\n";
        }
    } catch (const Xapian::Error &e) {
        std::cout << e.get_description() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

}

int main()
{
    document d1,d2;
    d1.title = "Xapain is good";
    d1.content = "Xapian is an open source search engine library, which allows developers to add advanced indexing and search facilities to their own applications.";
    d1.url = "http://www.xapian.org";
    d2.title = "Xapain is awesome";
    d2.content = "good Xapian is an open source search engine library, which allows developers to add advanced indexing and search facilities to their own applications.";
    d2.url = "http://www.xapian.org/test";
    indexData(d1);
    indexData(d2);
    searchData("xapian title:good");
    searchData("xapian title:Xapian is good");
    return 0;
}
```

First query "xapian title:good" works well.

But "xapian title:Xapian is good" fails.

Can any one please explain what is the issue

Comment: Your main problem is that you're setting prefixes such as `title` and `content`, but then mapping field names in the `QueryParser` to the empty prefix (eg: `qp.add_prefix("", "title");`). You usually want to use a capitalized prefix, since this is what the `TermGenerator` and `QueryParser` are designed to work with: `indexer.index_text(d.title,1,"S");` and `qp.add_prefix("S","title");`.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the title as:

`d1.title = "Xapain is good";`

and your searching query is :

`searchData("xapian title:Xapian is good");`

Could the problem be that you have just mispelled "Xapian" for "Xapain" ?

Answer (score -1):

In searchData() method, you should include

```
document d;

qp.add_prefix(d.title,"title");
qp.add_prefix(d.content,"content");
```

instead of

```
qp.add_prefix("","title");
qp.add_prefix("","content");
```

Comment: I'm not sure what that will actually do, but it's not going to do what's needed here. The first parameter to `add_prefix()` is the prefix stored in the database (in the question this is made complicated by using the field name as the prefix).